# Unique according to the third column of data delivered by a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have a very extensive formula in `E2` that delivers these data in `column E - F - G`

I would like to know how I can add within my formula (`E2`) a way to add `UNIQUE` specifically according to the values in `Column G`.

I will not put the formula in the question because it is too big, so I will leave the link to the spreadsheet in case it is necessary to analyze the formula as a whole.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13FwHxEUz_dYzv4taarj_VzPI6yofYurwqUwSYIrHoN0/edit?usp=sharing

> For example:

There is a value:

```
2020/03/13 - PSTP - LINK/3031297/
```

And also the value:

```
2020/03/13 - 20:20 - LINK/3031297/
```

**The correct thing would be that after `UNIQUE`, only this value would remain:**

```
2020/03/13 - PSTP - LINK/3031297/
```

Comment: I've got something for you, it's a bit ugly, but it gets the job done. I took a UNIQUE() of JUST column 3 of your crazy formula, then used that as a vlookup [search key] back into the same table. You'll find it on the MK.Help tab. Again, too big to bother posting here.

Comment: Why the correct answer is `2020/03/13 - PSTP - LINK/3031297/`? Is it because that's the first occurrence of the link?  You could probably use `QUERY` if `UNIQUE` is not working for you.

Comment: @Raserhin yeah mate, because that's the first occurrence!

Comment: I saw your sheet and it seems that there is a kind of chat going on. Do you actually manage to get an answer for your issue? The formula to get the links and dates is pretty crazy to be honest. But I guess that this is not the formula you want to be modified. I see that Matt used `QUERY` on his tab, was that the final solution?

Comment: @Raserhin In fact, he used ```VLOOKUP``` for the third column to become a search key. Well then, the formula I use is really extensive, so my need for a solution that was at least more direct, like ```QUERY``` to order that you only need to place ```order by Col1```. If there was any way without having to retype the entire first formula, it would be great. but so far I haven't found anything simpler.

Comment: @MattKing could be great if you could post the answer so it can be accepted and upvoted. If not let me know to create a community wiki answer so this question is documented and solved.

Comment: @MattKing Do the following, when posting the answer, in place of my formula, put ```"YOUR FORMULA"```.  So summarize and you can publish the solution to use ```UNIQUE``` in general cases with ```VLOOKUP```.  So I can vote.

Comment: I did.  It got "hidden" by a moderator who said that it was an unhelpful answer because it only helped one speCIFic person.  I don't know what to do?

Comment: @MattKing Try publishing again tomorrow and let me know right away so I can approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MattKing hasn't posted the answer I will post it myself as *Community Wiki*.

So if you get all the imports sorted already you can just create a range using brackets `{}` and after that `QUERY` them and use an `UNIQUE` statement with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

In your particular case with all the imports you can just go ahead and do it like so:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(QUERY(TRIM(
{
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet2!A2:C,Sheet2!A2:A<>""),{"","",""})
}),"select Col3 where Col3<>''")),QUERY(TRIM(
{
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D2,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D3,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D4,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D5,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(
{
TEXT(IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),"yyyy/mm/dd"),
TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a")," ",""),"hh:mm"),
IFERROR("https://int.soccerway.com"&LEFT(IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"),FIND("?ICID=",IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))-1),"https://int.soccerway.com"&IMPORTXML(D6,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"))
}
,{"","",""})
;
IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet2!A2:C,Sheet2!A2:A<>""),{"","",""})
}),"Select Col3,Col1,Col2"),{2,3,1},0))
```

And change the range inside `TRIM` to whatever you want to adapt this code.

#### References

- [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en)